# Naming convention for Test plan version

Tags: testing, test-plan

While writing test plan, very first thing we add is `Test plan identifier` heading; under that we create table with three columns: `Test plan version`, `Changes`, `Person who made changes` to keep track of changes in test plan.

As test plan keeps changing since there are changes suggested by developers, product managers etc and hence we should also add another row with `Test plan version`, `Changes`, `Person who made changes` in the table.

Following are my questions:

1. What should be first time ideal naming convention for test plan version? Should it be `0.1` or `1.0` or something else?
2. After each changes, test plan version changes; what should be next version name? Means, if first time it's `1.0`, next should it be `1.1` or `2.0`? etc

Are there any conventions suggested by ANSI/IEEE?

Answer (score 0):

Answering your 1st question, naming of a plan version should start with 1.0 and so on. Dont know of any ANSI/IEEE standard but thats what I've seen it being done as a tester

For your 2nd question, I have two-point answer

1.Addition for test cases after every test case review your version should be 1.1, 1.2 and so on

2.Addition of test cases after a test set is executed and new test cases are required, version   should be 2.0 and so on.

Then for version 2.0 again the same cycle is followed till all required test cases are written